# VB.NET: Load data from a MySQL database into a DataGridView control

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

I want to put the information from my MySQL database to a DataGridView(DataGridView1).

My "MySQL" **Columns** are

```
ID, Username & Password
```

The **connection string** is

```
"server=localhost;user id=root;password=;database=exdb"
```

The table in my database(exdb) is `"users"` and I have all the necessary connectors, MySQL imports & Re & references in my project.

What should I do?

Comment: That is a basic question that you can easily find sample for on google; here is a link: http://ycouriel.blogspot.ch/2009/10/c-datagridview-and-mysql.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's something you can search online and find an asnwer. Give this simple code a try:

```
System.Data;
System.Data.SqlClient

//create connection , replace userID/password if you have.
MySqlConnection con = 
  new MySqlConnection(@"server=localhost;user id=root;password=;database=exdb");     
con.Open();
//user the table name as per yours
MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter("Select * from table1;" ,con);

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
adp.Fill(ds);
//change name according to your datagridview
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
dataGridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Your importing SqlClient while using MysqlConnection, is that okay?

Comment: you imported 
System.Data;
System.Data.SqlClient

But you're using Mysql connection, is there no error with that?